# #selector is working only for root element not for child in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a confusion on selector when I define selector for root element(App-component) using id like below I am able to render the component

index.html

```
<body>

  <div id="root"></div>

</body>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
     selector: '#root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    title = 'helloworld';

}
```

app.component.html

```
div class='my-text' >My Root Component</div>


<div id='child'></div>
```

I am able to render parent component, However I am not able to render child component if I follow the same rule on defining in child selector

```
@Component({
    selector: '#child',
    templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child1.component.scss']
})
```

But I am able to render child component if i change the selector to
 `selector=[id=child]`

Why the selector definition worked for parent is failing in child?

Angular version 8

Comment: the docs: https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector don't talk about #selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular compiler [uses the following regexp](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/compiler/src/selector.ts#L11-L21) to parse selector:

```
const _SELECTOR_REGEXP = new RegExp(
    '(\\:not\\()|' +           //":not("
        '([-\\w]+)|' +         // "tag"
        '(?:\\.([-\\w]+))|' +  // ".class"
        // "-" should appear first in the regexp below as FF31 parses "[.-\w]" as a range
        '(?:\\[([-.\\w*]+)(?:=([\"\']?)([^\\]\"\']*)\\5)?\\])|' +  // "[name]", "[name=value]",
                                                                   // "[name="value"]",
                                                                   // "[name='value']"
        '(\\))|' +                                                 // ")"
        '(\\s*,\\s*)',                                             // ","
'g');
```

As you can see there is no selector by id.

Moreover, your selectors `#root` and `#child` will be matched to `root` and `child` elements. So, if you replace `<div id='child'></div>` with `<child></child>` then the child component will be rendered.

Why root selector works?

That's because root component is treated specially and bootstrapped as dynamic component by using the following code:

```
componentFactory.create(Injector.NULL, [], selectorOrNode, ngModule);
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                             #root
```

Where under the hood Angular uses `document.querySelector(selectorOrNode)` to find dedicated element if we provided string.

On the other hand, all nested components are only rendered if they selectors match against elements in the template.